# Scope of variable in Python "with" statement

Tags: python, flask, with-statement

I have a `with` statement in my code:

```
@app.route('/users', methods = ['POST'])
def registerUser():

    ....

    if email is None:
        errorsList.append(Error("email","Email address not entered"))
    else:       
        # Check if email address is already in database
        with contextlib.closing(DBSession()) as session:        
            if session.query(USER).filter_by(USEREMAIL=email).count():
                errorsList.append(Error("email","This email address already exists"))

    # Add user to database
    user = USER(email,password)
    session.add(user)
    session.commit()
```

When I run this code, it works fine. However, I was expecting an error to occur because I thought `session` would be out of the `with` statement's scope and hence `undefined`?

I haven't defined `session` anywhere else within this function or globally.

Comment: It doesn't go out of scope, but session.close has been called, so you shouldn't try to use it

Comment: Side note: it would be nice if you followed everybody's convention by following PEP 8 (PEP 257 is also worth knowing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python variables stay within scope until the end of the method. There are no 'blocks' for scope in python